# How does this python code represent a weighted directed graph

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to do some hw with Dijkstra algorithm but I am having trouble visualizing what this input would like as a graph. The code is python. How is that a graph?

```
example = [[(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 3)], [(1, 3), (3, 4)], [(2, 3), (3, 5)], [(1, 4), (2, 5)], [], []]
```

Comment: You may represent a graph in different ways. This way seem to be a list of edges.

Comment: So would this mean 1 is 1 length from 2 which is 2 length from 4? @sashaaero

Comment: This is a list of lists of tuples. It doesn't inherently carry any more meaning than that. To be sure, you'd have to talk to the person who wrote it, or read some code that operates on it, or read documentation about it, etc. It could be lottery numbers for all we know. There are many possible meanings.

Comment: @rmcknst2 this list is really a bit strange, list of lists of tuples. Originally `(x, y)` means that node `x` has edge to `y`. Maybe each inner list means weight of edge, I can't really know.

Comment: @sashaaero yea the assignment is to write dijkstras alg. iven a non-empty directed graph with positive edge lengths, finds a shortest path from s to t. Returns a pair:(length of shortest path, path represented as list of node indices). And this is the input I was given.

Comment: If you really have no other information you may assume index of list as weight (starts with 1) and tuple as edge but edge (1, 1) with some weight seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the `i`th element of the list `example` represents all the edges with weigth `i`. You can change the data structure of the graph to something else, like a dict where each key is a node and its value is the list of nodes it's connected to, with the corresponding weigths.

```
example = [[(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 3)], [(1, 3), (3, 4)], [(2, 3), (3, 5)], [(1, 4), (2, 5)], [], []]

nodes = list(set([i for k in example for j in k for i in j ]))
arcs = [(i,example.index(j)) for j in example for i in j]

example_graph = {str(i):[] for i in nodes}
for i in arcs:
    example_graph[str(i[0][0])] += [(i[1],str(i[0][1]))]

print example_graph
```

This gives

```
example_graph = {'1': [(0, '1'), (1, '3'), (3, '4')],
                 '2': [(0, '2'), (2, '3'), (3, '5')],
                 '3': [(1, '4'), (2, '5')],
                 '4': [(0, '3')], 
                 '5': []}
```

Now you can implement the Dijkstra algorithm, here is an example I found :

```
from heapq import heappop,heappush    

def dijkstra(s, t, neighbors):
    M = set()
    d = {s: 0}
    p = {}
    new = [(0, s)] 
    while new != []:
        dx, x = heappop(new)
        if x in M:
            continue
        M.add(x)
        for w, y in neighbors(x):
            if y in M:
                continue
            dy = dx + w
            if y not in d or d[y] > dy:
                d[y] = dy
                heappush(new, (dy, y))
                p[y] = x
    path = [t]
    x = t
    while x != s:
        x = p[x]
        path.insert(0, x)
    return d[t], path

def neighbors(s,graph=example_graph):
    return graph[s]
```

For instance `dijkstra('1', '4', neighbors)` return `(2, ['1', '3', '4'])`